# JSON ajax returning null value

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am using jQuery to send data to Spring MVC backend. My Spring controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Response addAnsw(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Response answer = new Response();
    String name = request.getParameter("answer");
    System.out.println(name);
    return answer;
}
```

And my ajax method like this:

```
function doAjaxPost() {
var search = {
        answer : $("#currentanswer1").val()
}
alert(search.answer);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'add',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(search),
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
            + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "</pre>";
        $('#info').html(json);
        console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
          },

    error: function(e){
        $('#info').html("Sorry, there is something wrong with the data provided.");
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
}
```

The problem is, that answer is returning value, function ends up with success, but the string "answer" in json is null.

e.g `answer = abc` (printed "abc" with alert) and JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "answer": null
}
```

I am not using form attribute in my jsp (due to another jQuery logic, which doesn't seem to work with form attribute). What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is Response a custom class?

Comment: Yes, it is custom class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Response is a custom class im guessing the problem you are having is you havent assigned a value, you just created the object instance. Unles you assigned a value on the default constructor here. you just made an instance out of it

```
Response answer = new Response();
```

You are setting no value. for testing purposes try something like this

```
public @ResponseBody Map<String,String> addAnsw(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

and then assign a value

```
Map<String,String> test = new HashMap<String,String>();
test.put("answer","hi");
return test;
```

if you want your Response to work you can put a value in answer on the default constructor. or create a custom constructor. Or provide a setter to be able to set the value in

```
public Response() {
    this.answer= "My Cool answer"; // Asuming answer is a String
}
```

To Recieve data from the client in json you can do the following

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Response addAnsw(@RequestBody YourCustomClass yourRequest) {
```

Note that YourCustomClass has to either have all getters and setters or should be annotated accordingly so that Jackson can deserialize what you are sending to the server.

Hope it helps

Comment: I wanted it other way round. Get data from jsp  to server. But you answer set me towards right answer. I corrected  my code, and its working now. I am working first time with JSON, so have lots of things to learn. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question. Ive edited the answer to what you were requesting. care to upvote ;)

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I was trying to upvote, but I don't have enough reputation yet, as this was my first question.